# displaying option box using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 pages. First is dodaj_plan.html and second is option.php. I would like for user to use "select box" on the page dodaj_plan.html which would show all the options which are stored in my database. I would then like to use ajax to fetch those results from option.php and post them on dodaj_plan.html. Problem i am facing at this moment is that the select box on mine dodaj_plan.html is empty.

dodaj_plan.html code:

```
<form  method="post" id="test">
Izberi projekt: <select id="ime_projekta" name="ime_projekta">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
}); 
$(document).on('change','#ime_projekta',function(){ 
$.post('option.php',$('#test').serialize()).done(function(result){ 
$('#result').html(result); 
});
}); 
</script>
<div id="result"</div>

</select><br><br>
```

my option.php code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ime_projekta FROM smart_projekti");

echo "<select>";

while ( $db_v = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

echo "<option>" . $db_v['ime_projekta'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($conn);

if (isset ($_GET['update']))
{
echo $tbl;
die ();
}
```

What am i missing here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Write your specific problem. which problem you face in this process.

Comment: I edited my post. The select box on my html site is empty showing no options to select.

Comment: And where do this options should come from?

Comment: What result show on result div? & your result div wrap are wrong...

Comment: write your div like this:    <div id="result"></div>

Comment: u_mulder : i have database where there are projects...i would like to read em with php and use dropdown box on html which is called with ajax, so the user could select from 1 of the projects